# Angular - Fullcalendar: Obtener y editar eventos de una API REST - JSON

Tags: angular, api, rest, fullcalendar

Estuve buscando info sobre cómo leer y editar los eventos de fullcalendar desde una API REST obtenida en servidor desde una base de datos. En la documentación oficial hay poco relativo a Angular aún, sin embargo logré atar algunos cabos y creo conveniente documentarlo por si a alguien le resulta útil.

Me permito añadir esta cuestión para poder resolverla y que quede indexada para futuras búsquedas por si hace falta, ya que en castellano no he encontrado apenas información.

Comment: Hola Rafa. Hacer una pregunta + respuesta para aportar sobre un escenario/tecnología es siempre bienvenido, pero la pregunta tiene que estar bien formulada, como se espera de cualquier otra pregunta aquí. Necesitamos poner un escenario que muestre qué problemas encontraste, para a continuación ver en la respuesta cómo solucionarlos. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta, añadiendo el código que intentaste usar pero que no terminaba de funcionar correctamente o no sabías enlazar con el backend

Comment: @PabloLozano debido a que hace 7 meses de la cuestión, no dispongo del código, sin embargo anoto tu sugerencia y recomendación para futuras cuestiones. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo la documentación aportada y las anotaciones del código de  este enlace de Adam Shaw https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/angular pude obtener los datos de una base de datos de manera fácil. En el mismo código indica qué hacer, es decir, sustituir los eventos iniciales (configurados para que en la demo estén siempre en el día presente) por el setting events:

```
    calendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
        headerToolbar: {
          left: 'prev,next today',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
        },
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
       //initialEvents: `events`, // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        events: `${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/ajax/read_eventos.php`,
        weekends: true,
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        locales: [esLocale],
        select: this.handleDateSelect.bind(this),
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick.bind(this)
  );
```

en este caso no uso un servicio y paso la url directamente, cada cual puede obtenerlo como vea.

En el caso del insert event, sí uso un servicio para llamar a la API REST. Sustituyo el prompt del código origen por la librería sweet alert2.

```
    async handleDateSelect(selectInfo: DateSelectArg) {
     const calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;
     calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection
     const { value: title } = await Swal.fire({
      input: 'text',
      showCancelButton: true
      })
      if (title) {
        this.valor = JSON.stringify({ "id": createEventId(),"title": title, "start": selectInfo.startStr,"end": selectInfo.endStr,"allDay": selectInfo.allDay});
        this.eventosService.addEvent( this.valor ).subscribe( respuesta => {}); 
      } 
    }
```

NOTA: además incluí el idioma español que permite la importación del componente necesario y lo indiqué en las options de esta manera: locales:

```
      import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es';
      [esLocale]
```